# Load denied by X-Frame-Options: domain.com/attachments/do-upload does not permit framing

Tags: apache, server, x-frame-options

I was getting an error related to X-frame-Options, After lot of googling i found a solution.

Problem:
Load denied by X-Frame-Options: domain.com/attachments/do-upload does not permit framing

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issue by adding

> Header always unset X-Frame-Options

Add this to bottom of configuration file ( /etc/apache2/apache2.conf).
And restart the apache. ( service apache2 restart)